# Injected remote thread crashes when using a large local array?

Tags: c, windows, shellcode

This Windows example creates a remote thread in another process

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <Winternl.h>

#define RET_INSTRUCTION 0xC3

DWORD WINAPI shellcode_start(LPVOID lpParameter)
{
    DWORD myStackArray[1000];

    return 0;
}

void InjectShellcode(unsigned char* shellcode, int length, DWORD dwPID)
{
    HANDLE hProcess = OpenProcess(PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS, FALSE, dwPID);
    LPVOID shellcodeAddr = VirtualAllocEx(hProcess, NULL, length, MEM_COMMIT, PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE);
    WriteProcessMemory(hProcess, shellcodeAddr, shellcode, length, NULL);
    HANDLE hThread = CreateRemoteThread(hProcess, NULL, 0, (LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE)shellcodeAddr, NULL, 0, NULL);
    WaitForSingleObject(hThread, INFINITE);
    VirtualFreeEx(hProcess, shellcodeAddr, 0, MEM_RELEASE);
    CloseHandle(hThread);
    CloseHandle(hProcess);
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    unsigned char* shellcode_end = (unsigned char*)shellcode_start;
    while (*shellcode_end++ != RET_INSTRUCTION) {};
    unsigned int sizeofshellcode = shellcode_end - (unsigned char*)shellcode_start;

    InjectShellcode((unsigned char*)shellcode_start, sizeofshellcode, 12924);

    return 0;
}
```

The target process crashes when a large array is defined

```
DWORD myStackArray[1000];
```

The shellcode function starts with this prologue

```
DWORD WINAPI shellcode_start(LPVOID lpParameter)
{
00000001400010F0  mov         qword ptr [rsp+8],rcx  
00000001400010F5  push        rbp  
00000001400010F6  mov         eax,11A0h  
00000001400010FB  call        __chkstk (0140001210h)  
0000000140001100  sub         rsp,rax  
0000000140001103  mov         rbp,rsp  
...
```

But, if a small array is defined

```
DWORD myStackArray[500];
```

the process remains alive with this prologue

```
DWORD WINAPI shellcode_start(LPVOID lpParameter)
{
00000001400010F0  mov         qword ptr [rsp+8],rcx  
00000001400010F5  push        rbp  
00000001400010F6  sub         rsp,8D0h  
00000001400010FD  mov         rbp,rsp
...
```

**Update**

Adding this linker option [/Gs8192](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/gs-control-stack-checking-calls?view=msvc-170) prevents the crash and generates this prologue

> The number of bytes that local variables can occupy before a stack
> probe is initiated.

```
0000000000400000 48 89 4C 24 08       mov         qword ptr [rsp+8],rcx  
0000000000400005 55                   push        rbp  
0000000000400006 48 81 EC C0 14 00 00 sub         rsp,14C0h  
000000000040000D 48 8D 6C 24 20       lea         rbp,[rsp+20h]  
0000000000400012 48 C7 45 00 00 00 00 00 mov         qword ptr [rbp],0
```

**Question**

When a remote thread is created, why does the injected process crash for a *large* array?

Comment: Could you patch the call to `__chkstk` to just be a null jump? I don't remember off the top of my head what the function does - if it just checks limits you should be fine - if it actually touches the pages to have stack memory pages committed then you may have to mimic that in your injected code.

Comment: Just use a debugger to debug the injected thread to see what is crashing. Much faster than trying to guess.

Comment: `__chkstk` probes the stack to ensure that it is expanded sufficiently (i.e. pages are committed) to hold the array you have defined. You will need to mimic that functionality or you run the risk of access violations if you touch the array past the guard page at the top of the committed stack.